# How to install and use openEHR libraries with maven

Tags: java, maven, openehr

I need to use these libraries https://github.com/openEHR/java-libs with netbeans and the installation guide tells to do:

```
REQUIREMENTS:

Java 1.6 or higher
Maven 3.0.4 or higher

INSTALATION INSTRUCTIONS:

INSTALLATION:

java-libs/mvn clean install
```

I meet the Java requirements and my NetBeans has bundled Maven 3.0.5, but I can't find a way to install and use the libraries in a Java project, could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These instructions are for installing the java-libs artifact to your local maven artifacts repository, so it can be referenced by your project.

#### Installing

1. Actually, you'll first need to [clone](https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/) the [java-libs repo](https://github.com/openEHR/java-libs) to your machine.
2. Then run `mvn clean install` inside the new directory created with the cloned repo.

#### Using

After you install the artifact, you can use it in your project by adding a [dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to your project's pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>openehr</groupId>
  <artifactId>ref_impl_java</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependency>
```

How do I know the parameters above? By looking at the [java-libs' pom.xml file](https://github.com/openEHR/java-libs/blob/master/pom.xml).

**EDIT:** As @Jack pointed, one should reference the specific library needed as dependency, like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>openehr</groupId>
  <artifactId>archetype-validator</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you ;) Your answer was very clear. I was able to install the libraries and use them in NetBeans. Just in case someone with the same question reads this, I had tu put in artifactId the id of the specific library I wanted to use, like archetype-validator,because with the general one the build failed.